# Fragment transaction from activity not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So i have a main activity that commits the transaction of a fragment that inflates the activity with an image view just like a main cover, and with the button "Sign up" that takes you to the signUp activity. However, all of that does work like it shoulds, the transaction works and the inflater does too, but the problem comes when:

I am trying to call a fragment (signUpForm) from the activity (signUp). The root of the problem is that the fragment transaction to signUpForm is not working because the toast programmed on it is not showing, so it does not even get to the inflater.

**signUp class:**

```
    package com.example.joshumberto.workcon;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class signUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.sign_up_container, new signUpForm(), "signUpForm").commit();

    }
    }
```

**activity_sign_up.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_container"
    tools:context=".signUp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="look, i should have inflated companions"
        />

     </LinearLayout>
```

**signUpForm class (only pasting the oncreate method, other things aren't needed):**

```
package com.example.joshumberto.workcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class signUpForm extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText correo;
    EditText telefono;
    Button continuar;

    public signUpForm(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "i am supposued to be created!!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up_form, container, false);

        correo = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_usuario_correo);
        telefono = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_usuario_telefono);
        continuar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_registro_continuar);
        continuar.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }
```

**fragment_sign_up_form.xml (just button,textview and edit texts to inflate activity**)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/colorSignUpBackground"
tools:context=".signUp"
android:id="@+id/sign_up_form" >

<!--<include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />-->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Registro"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
    android:textSize="@dimen/titulo_txt"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_standar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_usuario_correo"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_login_btn"
        android:hint="Correo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_usuario_contrasena"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_login_btn"
        android:hint="Contrasena"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_usuario_telefono"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_login_btn"
        android:hint="Telefono"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Continuar"
    android:id="@+id/btn_registro_continuar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<!--<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/miLista"
    ></ListView>-->
```

Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout and use replace instead of add for FragmentTransaction?

Comment: Tried, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try replace() method instead of add(). like this.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sign_up_container, new signUpForm(), "signUpForm").commit();
```

Comment: Tried, same problem. However, i'd like to know the reason why you thought about replacing?